# Java rpg collision detection

Tags: java, collision-detection

So im working on a java RPG and I am stuck on the collision detecting. This is my map so far

[image: The map]

Im trying to get it so that he cant walk on the blue but can on the white ones. The way I am doing the movement is by making the map move by applying x offset and y offset to each textures x and y, and adding/taking away from them as the wasd keys are pressed. This gives the affect that the player is moving,even though its the map. This is the code I tryed for the detection.

```
int x_offset = InGame.current_level.xoffset;
    int y_offset = InGame.current_level.yoffset;
    Rectangle player = new Rectangle(Math.round((x + x_offset) / 256),Math.round((y + y_offset) / 256),256,256);

for(int x = 0;x!= InGame.current_level.width;x++){
for(int y = 0;y!= InGame.current_level.height;y++){ 
int tile  = InGame.current_level.tiles[x+y* InGame.current_level.width];
            Rectangle tileRect = new Rectangle(x + x_offset ,y + y_offset,256,256);
            if(player.contains(tileRect)){
                System.out.println("Standing on " + tile);
                return;
                }
        }
    }
```

But somtimes it says that he is not standing on any tile,and it is often wrong when it says he is on a tile. Each Tile is rendered by doing (x * 256) + xoffset and the same for y. the map is stored in int[] where each part of the array is a number,which corresponds to a tile id

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Generate simple images in memory - 3 x solid color will be fine.

Comment: The important part is the 'SSCCE'.

Comment: What Andrew said. Also, the indentation could be better, and you have some name shadowing which may or may not have an influence.

I may be wrong, but as far as I can see, the error may have something to do with mixing coordinate systems. Why are you dividing the position coordinates of the player rectangle with 256, but still having 256 for width and height? It may be useful for you to reduce the map while testing, and print out the position coordinates and the width and height of all the tile and player rectangles. Naming coordinates with what coordinate system they are in may also help.

Comment: By the way; can the player stand on multiple tiles, or only one tile at a time? And can the player stand in different places in a tile? If only one tile at a time, and the player cannot stand in different places in a tile, it would likely be a good idea to simplify things by simply giving the player a position into the map-grid, and determining the tile position that way.